# How to appear subsubsection in chapter in my list of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` to appear subsubsection (1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.2) but unfortunately it is'not  appear in my list of contents.
my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
  \chapter{the name of chapter}
  \section{section test}
  \subsection{subsection test}
  \subsubsection{subsubsection test}
  \subsubsection{subsubsection test}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
  \chapter{the name of chapter}
  \section{section test}
  \subsection{subsection test}
  \subsubsection{subsubsection test}
  \subsubsection{subsubsection test}
\end{document}
```